# JSTL cutsom date format using fmt tag

Tags: jstl

I need a date format like this.

```
11 November ,2015
```

I have tried using fmt tag.

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${Attr['DATE']}"  type="both" dateStyle="long" />
```

the output is 
November 11, 2015 12:00:00 AM.

How can i do that? Please help me.
Can i use any kind of pattern attribute?

Comment: I doubt this is a duplicate of the mentioned question. There they doesn't know at all how to do it, this question is about custom patterns inside `formatDate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: fmt:formatDate has a `pattern` attribute too.

Try `<fmt:formatDate pattern="dd M ,yyyy" value="${Attr['DATE']}" />` or `<fmt:formatDate type="date" dateStyle="long" value="${Attr['DATE']}" />`